# Url hacking in Sales Console

Tags: visualforce, developer-console, console

Does anyone know if URL hacking works on Sales Console? I want to activate sales console in my org but not sure if pre population of field will be affected by this.

Comment: are you currently using hacked URLs? if so can you share an example? alternative spin up a sandbox and give it a try

Comment: Yes I am using url hacking in my sandbox. For eg Account Plan is a child object of Account with master detail relationship. My hack url is:   /apex/RedirectWithVariables?object=Account_Plan__c&Account__c={!Account.Name}&ID_Account__c={!Account.Id}&Name="Account plan name will auto populate"&allowRTS=false&newURL={!URLENCODE(URLFOR($Action.Account_Plan__c.New_Account_Plan ))}&retURL={!Account.Id}                                                    RedirectWithVariables is a page which converts API name into SSFDC id. So you can treat this code acts similarly to the one we use in URL hacking.

Comment: I cannot test it in my org since sales console has to be activated from salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of google and Tried to implement the Sales console on my Developer org (Sales Console license only available in Developer & Proffesional editions, for rest we need to purchase this from sfdc). I found that URL hacking worked perfectly as it did in out normal sales window.

Thanks.